# Как вывести число Пи до определенного знака?

Tags: c++, циклы

```
long double ThisIsAPi = long double(M_PI);
int a = 0;
int b;
cout << "Vvv";
cin >> b;
for (a; a < b; a++) {
    cout << ThisIsAPi;
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}


system("pause");
return 0;
```

Comment: `printf("%.6lf", var);` вроде - 6 знаков. Ещё у `std::cout` можно было выставлять модификаторы типа `setw`

Comment: Если требуется значительное количество знаков, придется считать пи самому.

Comment: Можно записать в строку значение откуда-нибудь из Википедии с кучей знаков, и выводить столько знаков сколько вам нужно. Только не забывать округлять последний знак.

Comment: Вообще-то в стандартной библиотеке нет готовой константы для Пи. Т.е. нет никакого `M_PI`. Тут в первую очередь надо выяснить, что именно вам надо сделать. Если у вас это учебное задание, то, боюсь, оно состоит как раз в том, чтобы вычислить заданное количество знаков числа Пи самостоятельно.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Число пи можно считать использовав ряд Лейбница, выводить, использовав манипулятор

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;
int main()
{    
    double pi{};
    int j = 1;
    const int prec = 10;
    for (int i = 1; i < 500000; ++i) {  // бесконечный ряд
        pi += (double)4 / j;
        j += 2;
        pi -= (double)4 / j;
        j += 2;
    }
    cout << setprecision(prec) << pi;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: А почему 500000 циклов? Поскольку в мантиссе типа double 52 разряда, то количество десятичных знаков тоже ограничено (примерно 16). Наверное, правильно будет закончить вычисления как только новые значения перестанут появляться.

Comment: `(double)4` — это 4.0.

Comment: @bipll, да, это так. Только не понятно что вы хотите: уточнить, сказать, что  я написал что то неверное, показать свои знания или  опубликовать информацию?...

Comment: Всем остальным сообщить, что это пишется проще гораздо.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй `std::cout.precision(7);`

Answer (score 0):

Вот, развлекался как-то. Алгоритм Spigot. Вывод пи с точностью, указываемой в командной строке:

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

string Pi(int N)
{
    int M = (N*10+2)/3;
    vector<int> r(M,2);
    string pi;
    pi.reserve(N+1);
    for(int i = 0; i < N; ++i)
    {
        int carry = 0;
        int sum = 0;
        for(int j = M-1; j >= 0; --j)
        {
            r[j] *= 10;
            sum = r[j] + carry;
            int q = sum / (2*j+1);
            r[j]  = sum % (2*j+1);
            carry = q * j;
        }
        r[0] = sum % 10;
        int q = sum / 10;
        if (q >= 10)
        {
            q = q - 10;
            for(int j = pi.length()-1;;--j)
            {
                if (pi[j] == '9')
                    pi[j] = '0';
                else
                {
                    ++pi[j];
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        pi += ('0' + q);
        if (i== 0) pi += '.';
    }
    return pi;
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    cout << Pi((argc == 1) ? 10 : atoi(argv[1])) << endl;
}
```